# SpriteKit SKCameraNode - Nil when unwrapping an optional value just after assigned

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, option-type, skscene

I'm using SpriteKit in an iOS app, and trying to initialize the `camera` property of my SKScene in the overridden `didMoveToView` method. If I just initialize it like so:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    ...
    self.camera = SKCameraNode()
    self.addChild(self.camera!)
}
```

...it throws the exception `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at the `self.addChild` line, but if I do this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    ...
    let camera = SKCameraNode()
    self.camera = camera
    self.addChild(self.camera!)
}
```

...it works fine, no exception. Why are these two ways different? Is there some kind of garbage collection happening? Its not inconvenient to use the second format, that works, but I'm curious what differs that I'm missing.

Comment: Can you show us how you declare your camera in the first case please ?

Comment: This is it, I assumed that the `camera` optional variable in the SKScene (`self` here refers to an SKScene subclass) could be initialized and that reference would protect the camera object from garbage collection. `self.camera` is declared in SKScene files within SpriteKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `camera` property of `SKScene` is defined as `weak`:

```
weak public var camera: SKCameraNode?
```

Therefore, as ARC will deallocate any instance that doesn't have a strong reference to it ([Swift uses ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), not garbage collection) – as soon as you assign `SKCameraNode()` to it, it will be deallocated and therefore will be `nil`. You then proceed to force unwrap it (which you should [always avoid doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)), causing the crash.

Your second example works as you have a strong reference to your camera instance through your

```
let camera = SKCameraNode()
```

declaration, therefore preventing it from being deallocated while that strong reference to it exists (note that `addChild` will also create a strong reference to it).